# Change the color of symbols in D3-legend

Tags: javascript, d3.js, svg

I am trying to change the color of symbols in a legend. I have the following variable

```
var symbolTypes = {
"triangleUp": d3.svg.symbol().type("triangle-up"),
"circle": d3.svg.symbol().type("circle")
};
```

which I use to create an ordinal scale

```
var symbolScale = d3.scale.ordinal()
  .domain(['negative', 'positive'])
  .range([symbolTypes.circle(), symbolTypes.circle()]);
```

then I add the legend as follows

```
var legendPath = d3.legend.symbol()
  .scale(symbolScale)
  .orient("vertical")
  .title("My title");

firstPlot.select(".legendSymbol")
  .call(legendPath);
```

Now I want the circle in the legend (symbol) to be red and the triangle to be blue. How can I do this? I tried adding a color variable then defining legendPath differently

```
var colors = {"circle": "red", "triangleUp": "blue};
...
var legendPath = d3.legend.symbol()
  .scale(symbolScale)
  .style("fill", function(d){ return colors[d.type];}) // or attr
  .orient("vertical")
  .title("My title");
```

but it doesn't work. Any help? I am new to JavaScript/d3/svg.

ps: I am using [D3-legend](http://d3-legend-v3.susielu.com/) developed by Susie Lu

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that Susie Lu's D3-legend (v3 version) has no native method for setting the colors of a `legend.symbol`.

However, this is a simple task to do. First, set up a scale with the colours, based on the data, not on the shape:

```
var colorScale = d3.scale.ordinal()
  .domain(["negative", "positive"])
  .range(["red", "blue"])
```

And then, selecting the paths, apply the colors:

```
svg.selectAll(".cell path").each(function(d) {
  d3.select(this).style("fill", colorScale(d))
})
```

Here is a demo:

```js
var symbolTypes = {
  "triangleUp": d3.svg.symbol().type("triangle-up")(),
  "circle": d3.svg.symbol().type("circle")()
};

var symbolScale = d3.scale.ordinal()
  .domain(['negative', 'positive'])
  .range([symbolTypes.triangleUp, symbolTypes.circle]);

var svg = d3.select("svg");

svg.append("g")
  .attr("class", "legendSymbol")
  .attr("transform", "translate(20, 20)");

var colorScale = d3.scale.ordinal()
  .domain(["negative", "positive"])
  .range(["red", "blue"])

var legendPath = d3.legend.symbol()
  .scale(symbolScale)
  .orient("vertical")
  .title("My title");

svg.select(".legendSymbol")
  .call(legendPath);

svg.selectAll(".cell path").each(function(d) {
  d3.select(this).style("fill", colorScale(d))
})
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3-legend/1.13.0/d3-legend.js"></script>
<svg></svg>
```

Comment: Thank you for your response!
I have other symbols in the plot with different colors. When I use what you suggested, the others turn into one color! So basically what I am trying to do is generate a scatter plot with blue circles (negative)  and red triangles (positive) with a legend on the side. I can generate the symbols inside the plot with the appropriate colors what I am trying to work on is create a legend that maps correctly to the two types of colored shapes.

Comment: Your other symbols change the colour because in my code I'm using `selectAll("path")`, which selects **all** the paths! My code was a basic example, just to show you how to do it. Try again, using `selectAll(".cell path")` inside the `each`. That way, you will select only the symbols in the legend.